# I was asked this question in an interview...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> If I have a $10 \times 10$ sided cube (rubik's cube is $3 \times 3$ sided), and dropped it in a bucket of black paint, can you tell me mathematically how I could determine the total number of sides that are black?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking a larger cube into a smaller one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175067/breaking-a-larger-cube-into-a-smaller-one)

Comment: Not without the depth of the bucket and the quantity of paint contained therein, with respect to the size of the cube.

Comment: @Ted: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Arkamis The mathematical formulation of this is obvious...

Comment: Many answers. One could say $6$. Or if it is $1\times 1$ sides of cubelets, $600$. Perhaps they were really asking how many cubelets have at least one black side. That is less immediate.

Comment: Something like that may require counting a large (read: more than three) facets. I don't know any mathematician who can do something as complicated like this. The formula itself exists using the axiom of choice, but it is not constructive.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious answer would be $6\times 10\times 10=600$ since each face of the cube has $10\times 10$ "sides" on it and there are 6 faces of a cube.

However, if this one of those silly "lateral thinking" questions, perhaps the paint seeps between the "cracks" and in fact every "side" of each of the $10\times 10\times 10=1000$ "minicubes" making up a Rubik's-style cube is covered, so that therefore there are $6000$ "sides" painted black.

Comment: +1 for Silly Lateral Thinking. http://spikedmath.com/526.html

Comment: In other words: all of 'em!

Answer (score 3):

The actual question asked MAY have been: if you drop a $10 \times 10 \times 10$ cube into a bucket of black paint, how many "cubies" have AT LEAST one side with black paint on it.

In this case, there is an $8 \times 8 \times 8$ cube in the middle that hasn't been touched.  So the answer is $10^3 - 8^3 = 488$.